# php artisan serve does not showing any output

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to run a laravel project . But `php artisan serve` does not showing any output.

[image]

But other projects are running fine. Please help.

Comment: Try this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527826/351330](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36527826/351330)

Comment: xargs is not recognised as internal or external command

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice at first from your screenshoot you're on a Windows machine and that is a Linux command. But the advice in that answer still stands though, so try enabling error reporting for the app or look in the logs for any syntax or other kinds of errors.

Comment: storage folder exists in your directory?

Comment: did you restarted your computer and tried ?

Comment: @SachinAghera yes

Comment: @C2486 yes I have restarted